# Why would an Initialization Vector be supplied externally?

Tags: encryption, initialization-vector

My software uses a 3rd party encryption appliance. One of the capabilities they allow is for the client software to supply an IV while doing CBC encryption.

**Why would they not generate a random number on their own to use as an IV?**

What is the advantage of letting the client specify an IV?  I can only think of disadvantages, such as people supplying an insufficiently random number over a public network.

Comment: Could you specify the exact algorithm (cipher - e.g. AES - mode of operation - e.g. CBC - and padding - e.g. none of PKCS#7) for the appliance. This question is lacking information.

Comment: Or just specify a link to the appliance of course, you've sparked my curiosity now.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead - I've updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many reasons why the IV **could be** expected as an input parameter:

- it could be to let the user use his/her own random number generator, possibly because the device has none (as G_G has already stipulated)
- it could be to allow for creating larger ciphertext (as ArtjomB has already mentioned) by using the IV to contain the last vector
- it could be to let the user use a deterministic method instead of a random number generator (e.g. a random permutation of an encoded non-repeating counter for CBC or just a counter for CTR mode encryption)
- it could be that the API doesn't allow for multiple return values, in that case the IV could be prefixed to the ciphertext, but the developer could have solved it by using the IV as parameter instead
- it could be to keep the encryption/decryption calls symmetric (you need to specify the IV to the decryption routine somehow)
- many protocols have specific requirements for the IV and it is a good idea to allow all possible protocols (this is basically the flexibility argument of ArtjomB with a specific reason)

It may also be that there is no specific reason at all. We cannot look into the minds of the engineer that created the device.

Supplying an IV over a public channel does not *have* to pose a problem, but it does raise questions about the security of the appliance.

Note that for chaining blocks in CBC it is required that the device does not pad the plaintext before encryption. If the intermediate plaintext is padded somehow then the result after concatenation would not be the same as the ciphertext that would result from a single call.

Comment: I'm sure there are more (e.g. for CTR encryption = decryption), but these seem to be the most common ones. None of them invalidate the idea of generating a random IV within the appliance, it may be a better solution than the separate IV.

Comment: Another simple likelihood is that there are many cases where you need to perform encryption with a *specific* IV that's determined by part of the protocol, and can't be random. So an encryption appliance would need to provide APIs to support these types of use.

Comment: @StephenTouset Agreed and important enough to integrate into the answer, thanks for the additional argument!

Answer (score 4):

It offers more flexibility in using that API. Having a separate IV parameter enables bigger plaintexts than would not be possible in a single invocation, because of for example memory restrictions.

I assume [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) is used. You generate the IV and invoke the encryption on the first part of the big plaintext with the generated IV. For every other part of the plaintext, you take the last block of the previous ciphertext and use it as an IV to get the ciphertext of the current plaintext part. You then concatenate every ciphertext part to get a ciphertext which is the **same** as you would have got in a **single** invocation on the **complete** plaintext.

Comment: Artjom, thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes, CBC is used and I understand the role of an IV in CBC (which is exactly what you describe). What I don't understand is why the encryption service cannot generate a random number to use as its own IV in the CBC. What advantage is there is letting the client specify an IV?

Comment: It could, but as I said, there may be some restrictions on how big plaintexts can be. Letting the user provide the IV, this limitation can be eliminated. This is *good* for the user.

Comment: Wouldn't IV be dependent on the size of the BLOCK rather than size of the plaintext? (sorry for so many questions)

Comment: @OceanBlue The point is, you split a large plaintext up into chunks. You don't _want_ a random IV on the second chunk. You want to XOR the first block of the plaintext of the second chunk with the last block of ciphertext of the first chunk; that's exactly what would have happened if you were doing this in one invocation instead of chunking. To accomplish that, you must set the IV of the second chunk to the last ciphertext block of the first chunk. Think about how it would work if your function was limited to processing one block; that's exactly how you'd implement CBC.

Comment: I think if the caller of that library has to know the details of CBC to use it with larger plaintext, it is not abstracted enough. It should provide a stream-like API, where the caller can pass chunks of data in several steps, and the stream takes care of the details.

Comment: One reason is because user may prefer another entropy source than the one shipped with the algorithm itself (If any). User got a super nice hardware rng and he/she want to use it. Another reason is that user wants to (or not want to) randomze the encryption algorithm (i.e. to output different chypertexts for the same plaintext)

Comment: @G_G Good point. You should elaborate a bit and post as an answer.